# Compiling a netbeans program on the commandline

Tags: java, netbeans, command-line, import, compiler-errors

I wrote a program in Netbeans for my own use, but now someone else wants to use it remotely from the command line and give command line arguments. I changed the code up to accept commandline arguments but I can't seem to get the code to run correctly. If I type this (all the required command line args):

```
    java -jar /home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/consistentBelow/dist/consistentBelow.jar
    -o /home/Stephanie/Data/out9.txt //where the output file should be
    -f /home/Stephanie/Data/  //what folder the files are located in
    -c /home/Stephanie/Data/48E_cov1.txt //file
    -l /home/Stephanie/Data/list.txt //file
    48.doc //sample
    48e.doc //sample
```

It runs just fine, but never produces the output file. I tried to recompile from the command line (thinking, perhaps it is running an older compiled version) but it isn't recognizing one of the packages I downloaded to make the command line arguments:

```
javac /home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/consistentBelow/src/consistentbelow/ConsistentBelow.java 
/home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/consistentBelow/src/consistentbelow/ConsistentBelow.java:9: package com.martiansoftware.jsap does not exist
import com.martiansoftware.jsap.*;
^
```

I tried to mess around with class path but I can't seem to get anywhere:

```
javac -jar /home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/consistentBelow/src/consistentbelow/ConsistentBelow.jar -classpath /home/Stephanie/Downloads/JSAP-2.1.jar 
Unable to access jarfile /home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/consistentBelow/src/consistentbelow/ConsistentBelow.jar
```

(Also, if I try to run the program in Netbeans, it seems like it is ok. It just grumps about not having the arguments, as I would expect)

```
Error: Parameter 'out' is required.
Error: Parameter 'folder' is required.
Error: Parameter 'coverage' is required.
Error: Parameter 'list' is required.
Error: Parameter 'samplefile' is required.
Usage: java consistentbelow.ConsistentBelow
                (-o|--outputlocation) <out> (-f|--folder) <folder> (-c|--coverage) <coverage> (-l|--list) <list> samplefile1 samplefile2 ... samplefileN

  (-o|--outputlocation) <out>
        Where would you like the resulting file to be put? Full path and desired
        file name

  (-f|--folder) <folder>
        What folder will we find the sample files in? Full path

  (-c|--coverage) <coverage>
        Where is the coverage file? Full path

  (-l|--list) <list>
        Where is the interval list file? Full path

  samplefile1 samplefile2 ... samplefileN
        Please write the full file name for each sample we will look at

Java Result: 1
```

I can include code and output if it will really help to solve the problem but I didn't want to make the question huge if it is just a compile issue. 
Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Could you explain that answer a little further? I am not sure how to: -Make sure ant is in the path 
    -Make sure JAVA_HOME is set correctly
    -execute "ant clean" and "ant jar" in the directory of the netbeans project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just using netbeans to fix the commandline run. I made sure that my program was set as the main program then I used the little "clean and build" hammer and all of my problems went away.  `java -jar /home/Stephanie/NetBeansProjects/consistentBelow/dist/consistentBelow.jar -o /home/Stephanie/out9.txt -f /home/Stephanie/ -c /home/Stephanie/Data/48cov1.txt -l /home/Stephanie/Data/list.txt 48e.doc 48.doc`  worked just fine after that